# Inserting String in Relative path in Java

Tags: java, filepath

I have a path as below

```
    ConfigFactory oConfig = new ConfigFactory(sBaseUrl,
                "abc",
                "12345",
         "/u/toy/apps/JETTY/instances/US_32970_test/pop-mm_3.0.201/config"
                );
```

`32970` in the above path should come from `String Queue = "32930"`

How can i append value of Queue in the path

Comment: You can't append into the middle of the string. As the name suggests, *append* adds to the end. You just need the *string concatenation*, what's pretty elementary operation in the programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat the String:

```
"/u/toy/apps/JETTY/instances/US_" + Queue + "_test/pop-mm_3.0.201/config"
```

Comment: But US_" + Queue + "_test value keeps on changing and i want to put something like "/u/toy/apps/JETTY/instances/../pop-mm_3.0.201/config" , but it doesn't accepts ..             any idea will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Use [`String.format(String, Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

```
String.format(
    "/u/toy/apps/JETTY/instances/US_%s_test/pop-mm_3.0.201/config",
    Queue)
```

Comment: and if US_32970_test is only one file in the path always which always changes name, how can we use something like /../ . I used /u/toy/apps/JETTY/instances/..t/pop-mm_3.0.201/config but it doesn't work

Comment: can anyone help here